# Python how to prepend element in list to another list of strings

Tags: python, prepend

I have a list (list1) as follows:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

I want to prepend each element to a list (`list2`) of strings:

```
['Start|983471|String1|True\n',
 'Start|983472|String2|True\n',
 'Start|983473|String3|True\n']
```

to give:

```
['0|Start|983471|String1|True\n',
 '1|Start|983472|String2|True\n',
 '2|Start|983473|String3|True\n']
```

My code:

```
Finallist = []
x=0
while x < len(list1):
    for line in list2:
        Finallist.append("|".join((str(list1[x]),line)))
    x+=1
```

This gives back 9 lines. What's wrong?
I would expect each item to be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enumerate` and `zip` will do the work:

```
list1 = [0, 1, 2]

data1 = ['Start|983471|String1|True\n',
 'Start|983472|String2|True\n',
 'Start|983473|String3|True\n']

for i, (line, num) in enumerate(zip(data1[:], list1)):
    data1[i] = str(num) + '|' + line

print(data1)
```

Output:

```
['0|Start|983471|String1|True\n', '1|Start|983472|String2|True\n', '2|Start|983473|String3|True\n']
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you effectively have 2 loops, one that goes through `x` from `0` to the length of the list and another one that goes through each line in the list so it looks like:

```
for x in range(len(list1)):
    for line in list2:
        Finallist.append("|".join((str(list1[x]),line)))
```

So you will be appending every line, on each iteration through `list1`. You probably wanted something like:

```
for x in range(len(list1)):
    Finallist.append("|".join((str(list1[x]),list2[x])))
```

Here's how to do it more compactly with a list comprehension:

```
>>> list1 = [0, 1, 2]
>>> list2 = ['Start|983471|String1|True\n',
 'Start|983472|String2|True\n',
 'Start|983473|String3|True\n']
>>> ['{0}|{1}'.format(num, s) for num, s in zip(list1, list2)]
['0|Start|983471|String1|True\n', '1|Start|983472|String2|True\n', '2|Start|983473|String3|True\n']
```

I observe you are just using the index of each line, so instead you could use:

```
['{0}|{1}'.format(i, s) for i, s in enumerate(list2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use `for` loop .. .`while` loop is sufficient..

```
list1=['Start|983471|String1|True\n', 'Start|983472|String2|True\n', 'Start|983473|String3|True\n']
list2=['1','2','3']   
Finallist = []
x=0
while x < len(nk):
    Finallist.append(str(list2[x])+'|'+list1[x])
    x+=1
```

Comment: An index for both, that's where i went wrong. All suggestions very good. Thanks.